# Passing a superclass function as non typename template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose you have

```
  struct A{
  void f(){}
};


struct B:public A{
};


template<typename C,void (C::*f)()>
struct Call{

  void operator()(C* c){
    (c->*f)();
  }
};
```

why does

```
int main(){
  void (B::*f)()=&B::f;    
}
```

work but

```
 Call<B,&B::f> a;
```

doesn't, complaining

```
could not convert template argument ‘&A::f’ to ‘void (B::*)()
```

?

(`Call<A,&A::f>` clearly works)

In a similar way

```
const void (B::*f)()=&B::f;
```

gives

```
cannot convert ‘void (A::*)()’ to ‘const void (B::*)()’ in initialization
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void (B::*f)()=&B::f;
```

works because implicit conversion from

```
void (A::*f)()
```

to

```
void (B::*f)()
```

is applied.

**4.11 (2)**

A prvalue of type “pointer to member of B of type cv T”, where B is a class type, can be converted to a
prvalue of type “pointer to member of D of type cv T”, where D is a derived class (Clause 10) of B.

However, the standard doesn't allow any conversions for pointer to member function in template arguments except of nullptr_t conversion:

**14.3.2**

For a non-type template-parameter of type pointer to member function, if the template-argument is of
type std::nullptr_t, the null member pointer conversion (4.11) is applied; otherwise, no conversions
apply. If the template-argument represents a set of overloaded member functions, the matching member
function is selected from the set (13.4).

Comment: Great,thank you! By the way,do you also know const void (B::*f)()=&B::f; is not accepted as well?

Comment: @Fabio:  void (B::* const f)()=&B::f works fine :).  const void (B::*f)() means pointer to method returning const void value, so  signatures of the methods are mismatching in the latter case.

Answer (score 0):

The error states exactly what is wrong, `void (A::*)()` and `void (B::*)()` are different types.

While in this case it seems like it should be easy to do, the general case becomes much more complex.  Consider what would happen if `A` had several virtual functions and `B` had multiple inheritance.  Pointers to member functions are very complex beasts because they have to account for that sort of thing.  Take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/09/70002.aspx

You could change `B` to:

```
struct B:public A{
    void f() { A::f(); }
};
```

So that `B::f()` actually exists.  Right now `B::f()` is an alias of `A::f()` which is obviously of type `void (A::*)()` and not `void (B::*)()`

Comment: I completely agree on your points. My wonder is why is it possible to have void (B::*f)()=&B::f; then.
Incidentally , const void (B::*f)()=&B::f;
is not accepted as well

Comment: @FabioDallaLibera There are different rules: template parameters have to be the same type while the assignment operator can use convertable types.  You wouldn't expect `std::vector<int> a; std::vector<char> b;  a = b;` to work just becase a `char` can be implicitly converted to an `int`.